# PHP how to get Mysql database details

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have uploaded a few files to my cpanel file manager. They all display nicely on my website online. I used to do something like this:

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "omicrome";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No database");
```

To connect to my Xampp mysql and apache. But now I have created the databases on Host1plus in Cpanel. Where can I find the db_host,username and password for my database so i can connect to it?

Comment: How about contacting these people https://support.host1plus.com/?#_ga=1.21149368.2091458641.1474488049

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that can be alerting you to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need should be in the tab called databases in the top right.

Comment: where, this dosnt help?